# is double locking in Singleton class is really required?

Tags: java

When designing a Singleton class, is it required to use double checking? Why can't I just put an `if` condition as well in the `synchronize` block? Or is there any break of it?

```
 public static Singleton getInstance() {
    synchronized(Singleton.class) {    
    if (singleton == null) {
        singleton = new Singleton();
      }
    }

   return singleton;
}
```

Comment: This isn't double checking.  (Oh I see, you did that on purpose.  Double checking allows "faster access" in the case where the singleton is already created.  It's an optimization, you don't *need* it.)

Comment: Use an `enum` to implement `Singleton`. The lazy initialization pattern is not particularly safe.

Comment: You can, but if you have an `if` check _outside_ the sync block, you can avoid entering the sync block unnecessarily. Entering a sync block is expensive.

Comment: Thanks @Khelwood  , crisp and exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The check outside of the `synchronized` is not required, however, it will improve performance as long as you call `getInstance()` more than once. Using `synchronized` is very expensive, but just checking `== null` is very cheap. Usually, when you call `getInstance()`, there will already be an instance constructed, so if you always check `== null` first you can minimize the number of times you use `synchronized`.

Answer (score 0):

Safe way is by using enums. Here is example

```
public enum SingletonEnum {

INSTANCE;

int value;

public int getValue() {

    return value;

    }

public void setValue(int value) {

    this.value = value;

    }
}
```

Main class

```
public class EnumDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SingletonEnum singleton = SingletonEnum.INSTANCE;

    System.out.println(singleton.getValue());

    singleton.setValue(2);

    System.out.println(singleton.getValue());

    }

}
```

Comment: This didn't explain anything. Can you give more of an explanation why this is the right approach?